# htmlagilitypack not loading full content of the page

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to screen scrap a website with the given urls. When I try to load the content of the page http://cks.nice.org.uk/?char=B , I get all the content (in doc object below) except links (anchor elements) inside div with class="list-wrapper"

Any ideas? thanks

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = null;
    doc = web.Load("http://cks.nice.org.uk/?char=B");
}
```

}

Comment: Had a quick look at the page - it seems like the part of the document you're after is added dynamically with JavaScript while the page is loading, or just after. I'm not sure how you'll be able to retrieve those dynamic elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. I guess you are right but wondering if any one can give me a tip how to load the bit I m looking for.

Comment: have you found the way???i have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the HtmlAgilityPack or C# in general, but I can tell you from a scraping perspective what I'd do.

The document you need to get is http://cks.nice.org.uk/js/topics.txt which provides a nice JSON structure of the topic names and their URL. Parse that, and you'll see an array of objects like:

```
{"Title":"Achilles tendinopathy","Slug":"achilles-tendinopathy","Specialities":["Injuries","Musculoskeletal"]},
{"Title":"Acne vulgaris","Slug":"acne-vulgaris","Specialities":["Skin and nail"]}
```

Take the "Slug" from each and append to the base URL to get each topic page, e.g. http://cks.nice.org.uk/achilles-tendinopathy